# Tricky LINQ and nested collection

Tags: linq

I am trying to figure out an easier way I can take the following code and condense it into as few lines as possible.  Ideally, I would like to get an IDictionary> out of this.

```
 var report = db.Reports.Select(rid => rid.ID == reportId) as Report;
 Dictionary<string, List<string>> notes = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
 foreach (var subreport in report.SubReports)
 {
   foreach (var subreportitem in subreport.SubReportItems)
   {
     notes[subreportitem.Title] = new List<string>();
     foreach (var note in subreportitem.SubReportItemNotes)
     {
        notes[subreportitem.Title].Add(note.NoteDetails); 
     }
   }
 }
```

Ideally, I had wanted to do something like so:

```
from report in db.Reports
where report.ID == reportId
from subreports in report.SubReports
from subreportitems in subreports.SubReportItems
from notes in subreportitems.SubReportItemNotes
//Unsure how to select into the desired dictionary...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be equivalent:

```
db.Reports
    .Where(rpt => rpt.ID == reportId)
    .Cast<Report>()
    .SelectMany(rpt => rpt.SubReports)
    .SelectMany(subRpt => subRpt.SubReportItems)
    .ToDictionary(
        sri => sri.Title, 
        sri => sri.SubReportItemNotes.SelectMany(note => note.NoteDetails);
```

#### Notes:

1. The first line of your code uses `.Select(rid => rid.Id == reportId)`, but I assumed this should have been `Where` instead of `Select`, otherwise you would end up with a collection of `null` because the `Select` results would be of type `bool` and the `as Report` would output `null` for each.
2. This only works if the `Title`s of all of your `SubReportItems` are unique. It is conceivable that one `Report` could have 10 `SubReports` and that among those `SubReports` there are two or more `SubReportItems` with the same `Title`. If that is the case, then you may need to rethink this a bit, otherwise you will get a `DuplicateKeyException` when you try to add a `Title` that is already in the dictionary.

#### Explanation:

Basically, we are taking the set of reports, and applying the condition that we only want reports where the ID is the desired one. Personally, I would put this in a separate line, and use `SingleOrDefault` instead of `Where` because I expect only one result.

Next, we call `.Cast<Report>` just because you are using `as Report`, so I guess you had a need for it. This may be redundant and unnecessary in practice.

The first `.SelectMany` call will get all `SubReports` of all `Reports`. Again, we probably will only ever have one `Report` object at this point.

Now we have a bunch of `SubReports`, but we really want to get all the `SubReportItems`, so we use another `SelectMany` to get those.

Now that we have all the `SubReportItem`s from all the `SubReport`s from all the (1) `Report`s, we create the dictionary. For each `SubReportItem` we create a key from the `Title` property, and then for the value we use one final `SelectMany` to get all the `NoteDetails` objects associated with all the current `SubReportItemNote`s.

Comment: Thanks!  This helped a lot.  I do have a question about your first note.  More often than not in my code, I do db.database.select(pid=>pid.Identifier == suppliedId); and I get my object.  Should I be doing Where instead?

Comment: @pendraggon87 I'm not sure what data access technology you are using, but the LINQ extension method `Select` transforms or projects items to another type. If you are indeed using `Select` and getting the result you describe, then it is not via a LINQ provider. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx